# View user name by id in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two table that I join in my controller.

**Here is my controller :**

```
$data = DB::table('classrooms')
->select('classrooms.id as classrooms_id', 'classrooms.*', 'joinclass.*')
->join('users', 'classrooms.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('joinclass', 'classrooms.class_code', '=', 'joinclass.class_code')->get();
return View::make('std_classes')->with('data',$data);
```

In my joinclass table I have `user_id`. Now I want to view user name and that has in my users table. How can I select in this controller and view my blade page. I try this many time but I can't.
Here is my view:

```
Teacher: {{$data->name}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select it first then you could use it as `$data->name`, so try to add `users.name` to select :

```
$data = DB::table('classrooms')
    ->select('users.name as name', 'classrooms.id as classrooms_id', 'classrooms.*', 'joinclass.*')
    ->join('users', 'classrooms.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('joinclass', 'classrooms.class_code', '=', 'joinclass.class_code')
    ->get();

return View::make('std_classes')->with('data',$data);
```

You could get the image also using :

```
->select('users.name as name','users.image as image', 'classrooms.id as classrooms_id', 'classrooms.*', 'joinclass.*')
```

Or get all users attributes in same time using `users.*` :

```
->select('users.*', 'classrooms.id as classrooms_id', 'classrooms.*', 'joinclass.*')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes sir its really helpfull. But i have a question. Can i select two data in same ->select query?? If yes what will be that query? If i want to select users table name and image also?

Comment: yes sir i already do that. can you help me for this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398763/how-to-validation-input-type-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 1):

Here, I added few modifications, You should try this in your controller

```
$data = DB::table('classrooms')
    ->join('users', 'classrooms.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('joinclass', 'classrooms.class_code', '=', 'joinclass.class_code')
    ->select('users.name as name', 'classrooms.id as classrooms_id', 'classrooms.*', 'joinclass.*')
    ->get();

return view('std_classes',compact('data'));
```

And use following code on view to display records

```
@foreach($data as $stud)
{{$stud->name}}
@endforeach
```